# Finding self-intersections on a polar curve

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a polar curve $r = \frac{2}{\theta}$ (which is a [hyperbolic spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_spiral)) and I need to find out where it self-intersects. When $\theta$ is restricted to positive values it never intersects, but when it is allowed to be negative it intersects itself infinitely many times. My question is how can we prove that the curve *does* in face self-intersect, and, if possible, find the coordinates of a particular intersection point (a general formula would be lovely, but it seems like a far shot.). I have a (rather strong) feeling that this is really easy but I'm not getting how for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polar coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ represent the same point if
$$\theta_2=\theta_1+2k\pi\,,\ r_2=r_1\quad\hbox{or}\quad
  \theta_2=\theta_1+(2k+1)\pi\,,\ r_2=-r_1\,.$$
For your curve the first case gives
$$\frac{2}{\theta_1}=\frac{2}{\theta_1+2k\pi}$$
which has no solution except for the trivial $k=0$.  The second case gives
$$\frac{2}{\theta_1}=-\frac{2}{\theta_1+(2k+1)\pi}\ ,$$
which gives
$$\theta_1=-\Bigl(k+\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\pi\ .$$
That is, for any integer $k$
$$\Bigr(\frac{-4}{(2k+1)\pi},\,-\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\Bigr)\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  \Bigr(\frac{4}{(2k+1)\pi},\,\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\Bigr)$$
are the same point.

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed and more.

Comment: There is another way for polar coordinates to represent the same point: if $r_1 = r_2 =0$, no matter what their respective angles are. Of course, it's irrelevant for this specific question since $r$ will never be $0$, but it's useful to note when looking for polar self-intersections in general.